# Basic Error Handling in VS 2015

Tags: c++, error-handling, visual-studio-2015

I have used stack overflow countless times, but in my quest to teach myself c++, I find it's time to sign up and be part of the community. My question is about chapter 5 in Bjarne Stroustrup's *Principles and Practices using c++*. The book examples, along with the lecture slides I've found online, show the error handling as follows...

```
    if (a <= 0 || b <= 0)
    {
        error("bad values");
    }
    cout << "the area is " << area(a, b)<<'\n';
```

I have done lots of research, thinking maybe it's a syntax thing that has changed in VS 15 or maybe its something wrong with the header file the book has us create. The error message I get is...

Unhandled exception at 0x74E5C42D in ConsoleApplication5.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x002CF5E4.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: What does the body of `error` look like? Maybe that's what it's *supposed* to be doing.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) is a standard exception (see [this error handling reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error) for more standard exceptions). My *guess* without seeing the `error` function is that it throws the `std::runtime_error` exception.

In other words, it's nothing specific to VS2015 or C++ in general, it's simply how error handling was designed for the examples in the book.

Comment: A quick search [shows](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h) this is indeed the case.